# Document.cookie пустой

Tags: javascript, cookie

В php задал cookie, теперь мне он нужен на другой странице того же сайта через javascript. Ввёл в адресной строке следующий код и получил пустую строчку.

```
javascript:alert(document.cookie);
```

На сайте Google, например, всё работает, выводит. Проверил через Chrome - всё нормально, существует, имеет значение и разрешён для скриптов (HttpOnly выключен). Создал новый php файл и запросил cookie через массив $_COOKIE, получил, всё нормально, а через JS всё никак не получается!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У Вас домен тот же, с которого и куки добавляются, и с которого считываются скриптами?
2. Путь у куки. Можно создать куку, доступную только для определенной директории, к примеру, и она не будет доступна по другому адресу.

Comment: 1. Уже писал. Да, с того же.
2. Cookie создавались через setcookie с использованием только названия и значения. Сейчас обратился в ту же директорию, где лежит скрипт, который создал один из cookie. В ней он доступен для чтения. Добавил параметр времени и пути в setcookie в php файле, теперь всё работает! Спасибо!